# select name from array, selected name print in listBox1 and remaining in listBox2

Tags: c#

I am having this error:
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I spent a long time trying to solve it, but I could not. Please I need help

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] generate = new string[] {"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7","Name8","Name9","Name10","Name11","Name12","Name13","Name14","Name15","Name16","Name17","Name18","Name19","Name20" };
        string[] n = new string[] { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10", "Name11", "Name12", "Name13", "Name14", "Name15", "Name16", "Name17", "Name18", "Name19", "Name20" };
        String[] a = new String[20];
        string name;
        int Num;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // START btn
        {
            Num = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            if (Num < 20)
            {
                if (generate.Length >= Num)
                {
                    for (int i = Num; i > 0; i--)
                    {

                        name = generate.ElementAt(i);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(name); // Print it to list1 
                        generate = generate.Where(s => s != name).ToArray(); // Delete name after using
                    }
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("Sorry, remaining names =" + generate.Length);
                listBox2.Items.Clear();
                listBox2.Items.AddRange(generate);

            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Max name is 20!");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that indexes in 20 elements array go from 0 to 19. In your code, you allow 20, wich makes an error

```
if (generate.Length >= Num)
```

You should remove `=` sign. Also, you should add `=` sign to for loop

```
for (int i = Num; i > 0; i--)
```

so you can include the first element of array (the one with index of 0).

Basically, if condition should look like this:

```
if (generate.Length > Num)
```

and for loop like this:

```
for (int i = Num; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: Thank you Misa for your explanation. After I change my code to what you told me I have this problem:
To print the whole 20 names, I have to enter (19) for Num

Comment: What is the problem there?

Comment: I want to get 20 names when I enter Num=20
My current code I have to enter Num = 19 so I can get 2o name

Comment: Change this `Num = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);` to `Num = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) - 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try 19 instead of 20 because when you count elements in an array you start by zero.

Answer (score 0):

this will let you place 20 in your textbox

```
            Num = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            if (Num <= 20)
            {
                if (generate.Length >= Num)
                {
                    for (int i = Num - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {

                        name = generate.ElementAt(i);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(name); // Print it to list1 
                        generate = generate.Where(s => s != name).ToArray(); // Delete name after using
                    }
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("Sorry, remaining names =" + generate.Length);
                listBox2.Items.Clear();
                listBox2.Items.AddRange(generate);

            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Max name is 20!");
```